postgres btree index unique constraint does not work
I have a table accounts_coin with unique constraint on (type, id), but it still have two rows with same value of (type, id), this image shows the problem: click
information might help:

postgres server version: postgres (PostgreSQL) 15.6 (Ubuntu 15.6-1.pgdg20.04+1)
I upgraded pg version from 9.4 to 15.6 two weeks age using pg_upgrade. I'm guessing this might be the problem, but don't know how to further look into it.

I've tried to insert another record that has the same unique value into the table, but it failed as i expected:
account=# insert into accounts_coin values ('UchihaWind', 2, 1, 0, 0, 1716860624);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_coin_type_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (type, id)=(2, UchihaWind) already exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

The id field is varchar. Is is possible that these differ by some invisible character? Like space or something?

@LaurenzAlbe Sorry for not describing the problem accurately, the problem is about having same values of a unique constraint btree index.

@freakish I guess not, cause I have queried them out by the same condition, or do you have any idea how to verify that?

what happens if you do id='UchihaWind'::text in your query?

I see. That is data corruption, possibly caused by a C library upgrade (did you upgrade the C library?). You can use the functoins in amcheck to verify that the index is broken. To fix the problem, remove all duplicate values and REINDEX the index.

@LaurenzAlbe Sorry for the late reply, I've run bt_index_check, and it reports  ERROR:  item order invariant violated for index "xxx", I also found other indexes reporting the same error, and errors like "high key invariant violated for index xxx". What is the cause of index corruption, Is it related to the C library you've mentioned, how can I check if I've upgraded the C library?

You have to figure out the cause. It could be bad hardware, a software bug or a change in the collation xaused by an operating system library upgrade. You have to know if you upgraded the operating system or not. Perhaps you can ask your package management software.
